# Exception when I want to load model with jena

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I am working with jena library. When I want to open this address:

```
model = FileManager.get().loadModel("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Shlomo_Breznitz");
```

I got this exception:

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Shlomo_Breznitz(line 54 column 8): Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName.
```

It is a bug of jena, because this exception occurs just here (other rdf which I try to read are OK) or is there something wrong with this rdf file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that the data being returned from DBPedia is malformed (which is unfortunately quite common) - putting the URL into the [W3C RDF/XML Validator](http://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/) also shows this error

The only workaround currently is to download the file and manually fix the error yourself prior to parsing it with Jena

Comment: Also, please complain on the [DBpedia mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dbpedia-discussion) so they get their act together and fix these issues.